# How to replace ILogger with Serilog for Azure Function

Tags: azure-functions, serilog, ilogger

I want to replace ILogger to use Serilog entirely.

It ends up printing extra logs about the function has been executed. Like e.g.

```
[16:01:10 INF] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '00000000000000000000000091D3F47A'.
[16:01:10 INF] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '00000000000000000000000091D3F47A'.
[2021-09-08T08:01:10.246Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '00000000000000000000000091D3F47A'.
```

I want all system logs to use Serilog instead of ILoggerProvider.

Below is the configuration I have in the startup class:

```
            var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Warning)
                .MinimumLevel.Override("Worker", LogEventLevel.Warning)
                .MinimumLevel.Override("Host.Aggregator", LogEventLevel.Warning)
                .MinimumLevel.Override("Host.Results", LogEventLevel.Warning)
                .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                .WriteTo.Console()
                .WriteTo.ApplicationInsights(TelemetryConfiguration.Active, TelemetryConverter.Traces)
                .CreateLogger();
            Log.Logger = logger;

            builder.Services.AddLogging(options =>
            {
                //options.ClearProviders();
                options.AddSerilog(logger, true);
            });

            builder.Services.AddSingleton<ILoggerProvider>(new SerilogLoggerProvider(Log.Logger));
            builder.Services.AddSingleton(Log.Logger);
```

I wanted to `clearProviders` but causes issues to Webjob:

```
[2021-09-08T08:03:39.026Z] A host error has occurred during startup operation '6b883c02-8241-4b65-999e-5ad502c02567'.
[2021-09-08T08:03:39.027Z] func: Invalid host services. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost: The following service registrations did not match the expected services:
[2021-09-08T08:03:39.028Z]   [Missing] ServiceType: Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILoggerProvider, Lifetime: Singleton, ImplementationType: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Diagnostics.FunctionFileLoggerProvider, Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
[2021-09-08T08:03:39.029Z]   [Missing] ServiceType: Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILoggerProvider, Lifetime: Singleton, ImplementationType: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Diagnostics.HostFileLoggerProvider, Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
```

In all my functions, I am using SeriLog

```
using Serilog;

        public Function(ILogger logger)
        {
            _logger = logger.ForContext<Function>();
        }
```

The log works but I do not want duplicated logs in the console.

And how can I get Azure's Log Stream to show serilog as well? Now it only shows basic logs by the ILogger.

Comment: But did you also configure the serilog logging inside your appsettings.json? If so it will log from code and from logging. I had some problem!

Comment: no, i dont have any settings for serilog in appsettings.json. Is yours working now?

Comment: My code works, follow this example I made in guthub: https://github.com/hgmauri/sample-azure-functions/blob/main/src/Sample.AzureFunctions.DotNet31/Startup.cs

Comment: I see. Are you able to get the logs to be shown in Azure Log Stream?

Comment: Yes, I get all the logs displayed in the Azure log stream... then I save to Application Insights or Elasticsearch

Comment: Oh thats interesting... I cant seem to get it appear on my Azure Diagnostic Log stream. May I ask what app service plan are u using or are u using windows serverless?

Comment: I tried your code and it seems like u are still using ILogger and not serilog.

Comment: Could you please refer this for using `serilog` and Azure's Log Stream to show `serilog` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57350466/serilog-written-to-the-ilogger-does-not-appear-azure-functions-v2 , https://shawn-shi.medium.com/proper-use-of-serilog-for-log-stream-and-filesystem-on-azure-app-service-a69e17e54b7b & https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-file

Answer (score 1):

I am followed the [Proper Use of Serilog for Log Stream and Filesystem on Azure App Service | by Shawn Shi | Medium](https://shawn-shi.medium.com/proper-use-of-serilog-for-log-stream-and-filesystem-on-azure-app-service-a69e17e54b7b) blog for using serilog in azure function. I am not getting any duplication values. Without `Ilogger` we cannot send the logging information in `Serilog`.

Please have a look [on SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57350466/serilog-written-to-the-ilogger-does-not-appear-azure-functions-v2) for more information.

Comment: Are u able to share samples of ur code? I came across the website as well but didmt work.

Comment: Hi @chiaDev, steps available [here](https://shawn-shi.medium.com/proper-use-of-serilog-for-log-stream-and-filesystem-on-azure-app-service-a69e17e54b7b). Let me know if you facing any issue.